# Unpivot Multiple columns in Oracle is not working

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a table like below

| Process_1 | Tab1_Count | Tab1_Process_Count | Tab1_Status | Process_2 | Tab2_Count | Tab2_Process_Count | Tab2_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tab1_Process | 123 | 123 | Equal | Tab2_Process | 123 | 126 | Not Equal |

I am trying to Unpivot the above like the below

| TABLEPROCESS | Tab_Count | Process_Count | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tab1_Process | 123 | 123 | Equal |
| Tab2_Process | 123 | 123 | Not Equal |

With the below query

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(       
SELECT 'Tab1' AS tab1_Process,
count(tb1.ID) AS tab1_count,
count(tbp1.ID) AS tab1_Process_count,
CASE WHEN count(tb1.ID)=count(tbp1.ID) THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END AS Tab1_Status,
 'Tab2' AS tab2_Process,
count(tb2.ID) AS tab2_count,
count(tbp2.ID) AS tab2_Process_count,
CASE WHEN count(tb2.ID)=count(tbp2.ID) THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END AS Tab2_Status
FROM table1 tb1
LEFT JOIN table1_process tbp1 ON tbp1.ID = tb1.ID
LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.ID = tb1.ID 
LEFT JOIN table1_process tbp2 ON tbp2.ID = tb2.ID
)
UNPIVOT
(
(TABLEPROCESS,STATUS)
FOR COUNT IN
(
(Tab1_Count,Tab2_Count) AS 'Tab_Count',
(Tab1_Process_Count,Tab2_Process_Count) AS 'Process_Count',
(Tab1_Status,Tab2_Status) AS 'STATUS'
)
)
```

but it is giving me error -- **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**

As per comment by Alex Poole tried `CROSS APPLY` method

```
SELECT * 
    FROM
    (       
    SELECT 'Tab1' AS tab1_Process,
    count(tb1.ID) AS tab1_count,
    count(tbp1.ID) AS tab1_Process_count,
    CASE WHEN count(tb1.ID)=count(tbp1.ID) THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END AS Tab1_Status,
     'Tab2' AS tab2_Process,
    count(tb2.ID) AS tab2_count,
    count(tbp2.ID) AS tab2_Process_count,
    CASE WHEN count(tb2.ID)=count(tbp2.ID) THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END AS Tab2_Status
    FROM table1 tb1
    LEFT JOIN table1_process tbp1 ON tbp1.ID = tb1.ID
    LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.ID = tb1.ID 
    LEFT JOIN table1_process tbp2 ON tbp2.ID = tb2.ID
    )
    CROSS APPLY
    VALUES (
    
    (tab1_Process,Tab1_Count,Tab1_Process_Count,Tab1_Status),
    (tab2_Process,Tab2_Count,Tab2_Process_Count,Tab2_Status),
    
    ) (Process,Tab_Count,Process_Count,Status);
```

It is working in `SQL Server` but it is giving **ORA-00903: invalid table name** in oracle

I am new to oracle, Please help

Comment: What error is it giving you? As it is, it will throw ORA-00936 because you have an extra `select` in the inner query. With that fixed the unpivot will throw ORA-01790, I think. You started by saying you had a table, but that actually seems to be the result of the inner query; there might be alternatives to get the get result you want directly from the base tables.

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole The extra SELECT is typo error, the error I am getting is ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved the expected result using the below **UNPIVOT** Query

```
SELECT TABLEPROCESS,TAB_COUNT,PROCESS_COUNT,STATUS 
FROM
(       
SELECT 'Tab1' AS tab1_Process,
count(tb1.ID) AS tab1_count,
count(tbp1.ID) AS tab1_Process_count,
CASE WHEN count(tb1.ID)=count(tbp1.ID) THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END AS Tab1_Status,
 'Tab2' AS tab2_Process,
count(tb2.ID) AS tab2_count,
count(tbp2.ID) AS tab2_Process_count,
CASE WHEN count(tb2.ID)=count(tbp2.ID) THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END AS Tab2_Status
FROM table1 tb1
LEFT JOIN table1_process tbp1 ON tbp1.ID = tb1.ID
LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.ID = tb1.ID 
LEFT JOIN table1_process tbp2 ON tbp2.ID = tb2.ID
)
UNPIVOT
(
(TABLEPROCESS,TAB_COUNT,PROCESS_COUNT,STATUS)
FOR (t,c,p,s) 
 IN
 (
   (tab1_Process,Tab1_Count,Tab1_Process_Count,Tab1_Status),
   (tab2_Process,Tab2_Count,Tab2_Process_Count,Tab2_Status)

 )
);
```